# Sprite Kit Game image scale by screen size

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, image-size

So I am creating a Sprite Kit game and I want to have the **same look on every device(no iPad, for now)**, as if it was the same scaled image.

**So far** I have my background images figured, 4 images for every screen size, chosen at runtime by checking the height of the screen. All my other images are designed for iPhone 6 plus, so I have @3x and @2x(66.6% of the @3x original image), that means I have iPhone 6 plus and iPhone 6 pixel perfect images.

**The problem:** Ran on iPhone 5/5s or 4/4s the images don't change size, they are as big as on iPhone 6, which is normal, they use the @2x. I want the images to scale by screen size. I know I have 2 options: use 4 sizes for every single image or scale the images by "screen height" / 667(iPhone 6). Both solutions are not good, because the first makes the app bigger and the second involves checking if it is iPhone 6 plus(use the @3x) and then scaling every single image, also **both add a lot of code**, I strive for clean code.

The first solution is acceptable, only if there is no other. Sorry for the long explanation, just want you to know what's going on.

Comment: You kinda hit the nail on the head with what your 2 options are. Either you create separate images for the screen sizes you want and load them accordingly or you use the setScale feature to scale your images. Having separate images is probably the way to go as you don't bog the CPU down with having to constantly scale all your images.